# Hey beginner still learning python

Tags: python

```
def firstdecision():
    decision1 = ""
    while decision1 != "Y" and decision1 != "N": 
        decision1 = input(" Do you belive the old man's story ? ( Y / N ) ")
        if decision1 == "Y" :
            print ("You take a bite of from the apple")
        elif decision1 == "N" :
            print ("You unsheath your hidden dagger and hold it to the old man's throat")
        elif decision1 != "Y" and "N" : 
            return decision1

firstdecision()
```

So trying to make a text based game as a project to help me understand functions, loops better and what better way to actually learn than to get involved. Anyways kind of stuck here after the user inputs Y or N how would I code it where I can make a new def function() where depending on their answer  (Y / N ) a different outcome happens?

Comment: Check your code...as written, it will throw an IndentationError.

Comment: `elif decision1 != "Y" and "N" ` must be `elif decision1 != "Y" and decision1 != "N" `

Comment: Please choose a meaningful title for your question.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is define the functions you want to call for each part of the dialogue and have a main function to call each one on answer, like:

```
def main():
    if (decision1()):
        decision2()
    else:
        decision3()
```

Where decision1() will return true or false depending on the user's answer.

By the way that is not a very smart way to make such game as you will soon run into a lot of function and if/elses, good exercise for beginners tough.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, yeah figured. Started to look into it more and learning a new way by making classes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define a new function at that point.  Instead, you define *both* functions *above* this point in the code.  Based on the user's response, you *call* one function or the other.

Comment: they don't need to be defined above, they only need to be defined above the call to `firstdecision`